# How to convert to and from two's complement and sign & magnitude?

Tags: python, math, integer, bit-manipulation, signed

How do I convert a signed integer in two's complement representation to sign and magnitude representation and vice versa in python?

```py
def twos_comp_to_sign_mag(twos_comp_int):
  # function definition here

def sign_mag_to_twos_comp(sign_mag_int):
  # function definition here

twos_comp_to_sign_mag(255) == 129
sign_mag_to_twos_comp(129) == 255
# Since:
# 255 in binary is 1111_1111 or -1 in two's complement notation
# 129 in binary is 1000_0001 or -1 in sign-magnitude notation
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks, I haven't confirmed that this will work in all cases yet, but what about converting back to twos_comp_int and a more generalised solution that handles arbitrary sized integers?

Comment: it was wrong anyway ...

Comment: Python `int` values are already in sign-magnitude form, except the magnitude is an array of unsigned 30-bit values. You are implicitly assuming a conversion from an `int` to a sequence of bits and back in both cases.

Comment: For arbitrary sized integers, it just .. doesn't work, at least not without something extra. All non-zero arbitrary sized integers have a leading 1, they all look like they're negative in that sense. If you decide on a fixed size, then there can be leading zeroes. Or you could represent a number as a tuple of a sign and a non-negative magnitude.

Comment: @harold that makes sense, thanks, but I still don't have an answer on how to do conversions with even an int8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only perform this kind of conversion on an integer with a fixed number of bits.  I've made it a parameter to the function.

The two operations are complementary, you can use the same function to go both directions.  You separate the sign bit, then complement the remainder and combine them back together.

```
def twos_comp_to_sign_mag(value, bits=8):
    sign_bit = 1 << (bits - 1)
    sign = value & sign_bit
    mask = sign_bit - 1
    if sign:
        value = -(value & mask)
    return (sign_bit & value) | (value & mask)

>>> twos_comp_to_sign_mag(255)
129
>>> twos_comp_to_sign_mag(129)
255
```